# setvalue() on v-text-field with nightwacth e2e

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nightwatch.js

I am querying on how to set a value to a text input of vuetify with nightwatch, below is my test :

```
module.exports = {
  'load a signup page': function (browser) {
    browser
      .init()
      .url('https://hfb-fronted-mock.firebaseapp.com/')
      .waitForElementVisible('v-btn', 3000)
      .setValue('Username', 'huxy')
      .end();
  },
};
```

Then my code I want to test is below :

```
<template>
  <v-col class="register">
    <Loader/>
    <v-text-field v-model="username" label="Username" dark required></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="firstName" label="First Name" dark required></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="lastName" label="Last Name" dark required></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="email" label="Email" dark required></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="nationalId" label="National ID" dark required></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="password" :type="'password'" dark
    label="Password" required></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="confirmPassword"
      :type="'password'"
      label="Confirm Password"
      required
      dark
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-select v-model="gender" :items="items" dark label="Choose Gender"></v-select>
    <v-btn class="signup_button" @click="registerUser"
   depressed>Sign Up</v-btn>
    <SnackBar />
  </v-col>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the actual `<input>` element in the html. Vuetify generates an id for each so use that:

```
.setValue('#input-312', 'huxy')
```

Comment: How do you get to know that it's `#input-312`?

Comment: Look at the site's source code. Each input will have an id. You will need to change `waitForElementVisible('v-btn', 3000)` as `v-btn` won't appear in the final html.